# UI action in middle of MvxCommand

Tags: user-interface, mvvmcross, commandbinding

I am using MvvmCross, but this may be general command binding.

When user click a button, the application require an extra input data before proceed to what I want to do in the actual command. The problem that I cannot call an UI action in middle of ViewModel, so just binding MvxCommand (or any ICommand) would not work.

One may ask  why:
1) I don't put an input on the UI and user can enter data before click button -> I don't have space.
2) Make default data, and let user change it later -> This my first though, but user tend to forget to change it later!!

So can someone come up with a solution? The only thing I can think of is forgetting command binding, and have code behind pop the ui for extra data, then call a method in view model!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

My personal preferred way is to use an "Interaction Request" - something that I learnt from the Prism framework from Microsoft patterns and practices.

In Mvx, you can do this using an `IMvxInteraction` property on your ViewModel. An example of this is shown in https://github.com/slodge/BindingTalk/blob/master/BindingTalk.Core/ViewModels/QuestionViewModel.cs

Each time an interaction is requested, the ViewModel provides an object to the View - in this case a `YesNoQuestion`:

```
public class YesNoQuestion
{
    public Action YesAction { get; set; }
    public Action NoAction { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public YesNoQuestion()
    {
        YesAction = () => { };
        NoAction = () => { };
    }
}
```

The ViewModel exposes the requester using an `IMvxInteraction<TQuestion>`  property:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
    : MvxViewModel
{
    private MvxInteraction<YesNoQuestion> _confirm = new MvxInteraction<YesNoQuestion>();
    public IMvxInteraction<YesNoQuestion> Confirm
    {
        get { return _confirm; }
    }

    public IMvxCommand GoCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
                {
                    var question = new YesNoQuestion()
                        {
                            QuestionText = "Close me now?",
                            YesAction = () => Close(this),
                        };
                    _confirm.Raise(question);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

The view on each platform can then bind and subscribe to the interaction request property. This is a little fiddly - because it uses weak references to prevent memory leaks - especially on iOS, but also possible on other platforms too.

Some example Droid code for this is in:

- https://github.com/slodge/BindingTalk/blob/master/BindingTalk.Droid/Views/2%20%20More%20Controls/QuestionView.cs
- with AXML in https://github.com/slodge/BindingTalk/blob/master/BindingTalk.Droid/Resources/Layout/QuestionView.axml

Sorry for the confusing `ConfirmationView` and `QuestionView` names here - the first is an Android `View`, the second is an Mvvm `View` and an Android `Activity`.

Also, please note that when implementing Dialogs in Android, then you need to be careful about screen rotation - as Android's Activity lifecycle can very much confuse things here - easiest mecahnism (I find) is to just handle screen rotation yourself rather than allowing Android to handle it.

Comment: I will try this later, but this look like the answer I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: In your example, is that because the ConfirmationView so simple so it does not have a corresponding ViewModel in the Core? In my case, user have to select an Item from a list (or click Cancel) to move on, so I have to create a ViewModel for "my ConfirmationView"

Comment: Would it possible to use Func<TResult> instead of Action so I retrieve data back instead just knowing which action user took?