# Binding with Dialog Widgets

Tags: mvvmcross

How do you bind a dialog widget with a class? The class in question is defined in the Core project.

I could not find any example of this so far. I am comfortable binding an axml to a VM.

EDIT

Seems this tutorial https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments should get me started.

However I am not sure how to show a dialog when a listitem is clicked. Above sample maps a button click event to a method in the view, and the latter shows the dialog.

My listitem does not have a view associated to it. It has a viewmodel though. How do I go about showing a dialog when the listitem is clicked???

Also, what is the rational for the snippet in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/HomeView.cs

`var existingDialog = (NameDialogFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag(NameDialogTagName);
            if (existingDialog != null)
                existingDialog.ViewModel = HomeViewModel.Names;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you bind a dialog widget with a class?

As you've already found, you can do this using:

```
        var dialog = new NameDialogFragment();
        dialog.ViewModel = HomeViewModel.Names;
        dialog.Show(SupportFragmentManager, NameDialogTagName);
```

> My listitem does not have a view associated to it. It has a viewmodel though. How do I go about showing a dialog when the listitem is clicked???

In general I do this use the `Interaction` pattern - see [UI action in middle of MvxCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639808/ui-action-in-middle-of-mvxcommand/22640623#22640623) for a worked example

> what is the rational for the snippet

It was probably to assist with Android rotation issues.

In general I don't do this much - I normally just turn Android's auto-rotation handling off and handle rotation myself instead.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd item (Interaction pattern), I ended up using a IMvxMessenger to notify the view, then let the view handle the display of the dialog. I did not know about the IMvxInteraction, will check it out. Any comment on which method is prefered?

Comment: I've taken a look at the sample code. I could not get it to run. Anyway, in my case I need to display a fragment in my dialog. The example code does not cater for this scenario. Care to shed some light how I can inflate a fragment into the dialog?