# MvvmCross custom binding display dialog

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

The goal is to display dialog for user to select date on tap on `EditText`.

I'm truing to implement binding that will show dialog on click. The code is the following:

```
public class EditDateBinding : BindingWrapper<EditText, DateTime>
{
    public EditDateBinding(EditText androidControl) : base(androidControl)
    {
    }

    public override void SubscribeToEvents()
    {
        Target.Click += InputClick;
    }

    private void InputClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime.TryParse(Target.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);

        var dialog = new DatePickerDialogFragment(Target.Context, parsedDate, OnDateSet);

        dialog.Show(
                    // Can't get fragment manager here
            , "date");
    }

    private void OnDateSet(object sender, DatePickerDialog.DateSetEventArgs e)
    {
        SetValueToView(Target, e.Date);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            if (Target != null)
            {
                Target.Click -= InputClick;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void SetValueToView(EditText androidControl, DateTime value)
    {
        androidControl.Text = value.ToShortDateString();
    }
}
```

But I cant find a way to get `FragmentManager` instance in order to call `Show` method of instantiated dialog. Can this be implemented in any way?

Comment: Generally I try to show Dialog's using the InteractionRequest pattern - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639808/ for a full explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to implement it:

```
 var act = (Activity) Target.Context;
 dialog.Show(act.FragmentManager, "date");
```