# How to run an Action on View before bound ViewModel Command is executed

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

As title clearly defines, I want to run an `Action` in my View just before a command is executed in the `ViewModel`.

### Scenario

Assume that we have a `NavigationDrawer` with two or more item types (e.g. `NavigationItem` and `ExpandableItem`). **Each item was bound to a command on its corresponding `ViewModel`.**

Now I want to:

1. Close the drawer before executing `NavigationItem` command.
2. Show an animation for the `ExpandableItem` before executing the command and do not close drawer.

I have tried the following approach:

### Core Project

```
public class MvxInteractiveCommand : MvxCommandBase, IMvxCommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public MvxInteractiveCommand(Action execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public MvxInteractiveCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
        Delay = 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delay in milliseconds to execute the action. Default is zero means immediate execution
    /// </summary>
    public int Delay { get; set; }

    public object InteractData { get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute();
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return CanExecute(null);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(new CommandExecutingMessage(this) { Data = InteractData });
            if (Delay == 0)
                _execute();
            else
                Task.Delay(200).ContinueWith(obj => _execute());
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        Execute(null);
    }
}

public class CommandExecutingMessage : MvxMessage
{
    public CommandExecutingMessage(object sender)
        : base(sender)
    {
    }

    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

**NavigationSimpleItem.cs**:

```
public class NavigationSimpleItem : MvxNavigatingObject
{
    private readonly IMvxCommand _clickCommand;

    public NavigationSimpleItem(string caption, int id, Action doCommand, Func<bool> canDoCommand = null)
    {
        ...
        if (doCommand == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("doCommand");
        _clickCommand = new MvxInteractiveCommand(doCommand, canDoCommand);
    }

    public override IMvxCommand ClickCommand
    {
        get { return _clickCommand; }
    }
    ...
}
```

### Droid Project

**MainView.cs**:

```
public class MainView : MvxActivity
{
    private MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

    public MainView()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();
        _token = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().SubscribeOnMainThread<CommandExecutingMessage>(e =>
        {
                DrawerWrapper.CloseDrawer();
        });
    }
}
```

**Notes:** As you can see, I use [Messenger Plugin](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#messenger) to interact between the `View` and the `ViewModel`. It works fine with my first need, which is to run a simple `Action` on every item click.

However, my view needs to know **which item** is clicked and what **its state** is.
I also want more complex scenarios later such as **waiting for an UI action** to complete before command execution (something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640623/359243)).

Comment: I think you have answered your question yourself.

Comment: @Cheesebaron No I don't! I'm giving up my solution since it is being more complex as I proceed. I really want to know whether or not I choose the right way to do this. Also I don't know how to tell the view which item was clicked to do a proper action.
I believe there is a better simpler solution to do such a scenario.